# A tag for mantle plumes/hotspots?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

[One question that'd benefit from this already](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/589/are-mantle-plumes-distributed-around-the-core-randomly-or-in-a-known-pattern/598#598), and as a somewhat controversial topic and an active area of research I'd be astonished if we don't get more. I suggest "mantle-plumes", as hotspot's more contested terminology (because it ascribes a particular process of formation to surface features). "hotspot" as a tag might also have its uses, of course, but I suggest its usage should be highly specific.

**ETA** per discussion in chat about etiquette, I've unilaterally created the tag. Happy to be informed if that's impolite and I shouldn't in future!